# Pandas column difference over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

**Edit at bottom **

I have a data frame with inventory data that looks like the following:

```
d = {'product': [a, b, a, b, c], 'amount': [1, 2, 3, 5, 2], 'date': [2020-6-6, 2020-6-6, 2020-6-7, 
2020-6-7, 2020-6-7]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
 product  amount  date
0     a     1      2020-6-6
1     b     2      2020-6-6
2     a     3      2020-6-7
3     b     5      2020-6-7
4     c     2      2020-6-7
```

I would like to know what the inventory difference is month to month. The output would look like this:

```
df
 product   diff   isnew  date
0     a     nan   nan   2020-6-6
1     b     nan   nan   2020-6-6
2     a     2     False 2020-6-7
3     b     3     False 2020-6-7
4     c     2     True  2020-6-7
```

**Sorry if I was not clear in the first example, In reality I have many months of data, so I am not just looking at doing the difference of one period vs the other. It would need to be a general case where it looks at the difference of month n vs n-1 and then n-1 and n-2 and so on.**

What's the best way to do this in Pandas?

Comment: Why is row #4 diff equal to 2?  There is no previous 'c' product.

Comment: @ScottBoston my guess is `c` is a new product which is not presented in the last month (`isnew` is `True`) so the last month amount is `0`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try `groupby` on the column product and `diff` the column amount for the column 'diff'. Then use [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) for the column 'isnew'.

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('product')['amount'].diff()
df['isnew'] = ~df['product'].duplicated()
print (df)
  product  amount      date  diff  isnew
0       a       1  2020-6-6   NaN   True
1       b       2  2020-6-6   NaN   True
2       a       3  2020-6-7   2.0  False
3       b       5  2020-6-7   3.0  False
4       c       2  2020-6-7   NaN   True
```

Comment: @MustardTiger this method like the one of Quang should be scalable to any number of months. what is the problem with this method if you use it with many months?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the key here is to find the `isnew`:

```
# new products by `product`
new_prods = df['date'] != df.date.min()
duplicated = df.duplicated('product')

# first appearance of new products
# or duplicated *old* products
valids = new_prods ^ duplicated
df.loc[valids,'is_new'] = ~ duplicated

# then the difference:
df['diff'] = (df.groupby('product')['amount'].diff()           # normal differences
                  .fillna(df['amount'])         # fill the first value for all product
                  .where(df['is_new'].notna())  # remove the first month
             )
```

Output:

```
  product  amount      date is_new  diff
0       a       1  2020-6-6    NaN   NaN
1       b       2  2020-6-6    NaN   NaN
2       a       3  2020-6-7  False   2.0
3       b       5  2020-6-7  False   3.0
4       c       2  2020-6-7   True   2.0
```